does any one know how to keep particles in volume from protruding from mesh in geometry nodes
I'm making a jello render similar to the vintage jello salads you see in those 1950s ads. I duplicated my main jello mesh, gave it a transparent material and also gave it a particle system with a collection (cherries and cucumbers) but I switched to geometry nodes because I didn't want the particles over lapping with each other. I'm trying to figure out how to keep the instanced objects inside the mesh and not protrude in the example photo. I'm still trying to understand geometry nodes. any help is appreciated, thank you!
